# Count the number of commits on Git since fork

Tags: git

We use `git rev-list HEAD --count` as part of our build process to generate a revision number.

We've forked this project, then added it to our private gitlab as a new project. When building this project want the revision number to only count the commits made since the fork.

What's the best way to achieve this?

I'm still new to git. Should we be tagging at the point of the fork and counting commits from there? Rebasing in the new project? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this, though I would caution that this method of generating build numbers might turn out to be limiting in terms of how you can use branches should your project outgrow your current branch strategy (as just one example).

You could use the commit ID of the last commit before the fork.  I don't like this approach because it's not immediately clear "why" when you see a command like

```
git rev-list abcdef12..HEAD --count
```

("well, why is `abcdef12` meaningful/").  Also, if you ever do a history rewrite that affects that commit, you'd have to update your build scripts for the new commit ID.  (But that kind of rewrite is a pretty drastic thing anyway, so that could easily never matter; I just prefer avoiding unnecessary limitations.)

Another option is to tag the commit at the fork (as you yourself suggest).  This mitigates both problems, as you can give the tag a meaningful name and move it as needed for history rewrites.

```
git rev-list project-start..HEAD --count
```

Or, since it's surely a constant, you could just one time count the commits *up to* the fork point, and in your scripts subtract that from the count.  In some ways this seems simpler, though I suppose it's actually a little harder to implement.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the limitations of this approach to build numbers, or suggest a better alternative?

Comment: @ChrisR - Not really. It depends on your project's needs and assumptions.  It *might* work just fine depending on how you use it.  e.g. if you only number master builds this way, and don't allow rewrites that take history away from master, and are happy with a monotonically increasing build number even if it isn't sequential... then this may be perfectly fine.  But in more general cases, depending on what builds you number or what rules your repo follows, it may be possible for build # to dcrease or be reused.  Make sure you understand when that could happen, then you can decide if it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the commit of the "fork point" (let's call it `abc1234` here) :

```
git rev-list HEAD ^abc1234 --count
```

or (alternative syntax, maybe more intuitive to read?)

```
git rev-list abc1234..HEAD --count
```

should strip from the list of commits those which are shared with the original fork source and give the right count.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to tag the commit and then count from there on.
One can achieve this with [git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list):

`git rev-list --count HEAD ^<tag-name>`

## Example

```
git checkout master
git tag -a v1.0 -m "The forked release"
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -am "added test.txt"
git rev-list --count HEAD ^v1.0
```

This outputs: `1`

if you're going to branch:

```
git checkout -b test
<We do 3 commits>
git rev-list --count HEAD ^v1.0
```

Result: 3

## Ignoring Merges

If you merge another branch into the current branch without fast forward and you do the above, the merge is also counted. This is because for git a merge is a commit.

If you don't want to count these commits add `--no-merges`:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --count HEAD ^v1.0
```